# Adding far future date on expire date

Tags: php, .htaccess, header

We can manipulate our expire date by putting this on our .htaccess

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
```

We want this to be manipulated inside our PHP file. While searching for a something like it. I came across with:

```
$offset = 60 * 60;
$expire = 'expires: ' . gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $offset) . ' GMT';
header ($expire);
```

But this only add time to our expire date. For us; we want the year to change. Is there a way to this in php?

Comment: Do note: "Set `Expires` to a minimum of one month, and preferably up to one year, in the future. ... Do not set it to more than one year in the future, as that violates the RFC guidelines." (from [Optimize caching](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching))

Comment: (No longer able to edit my comment above, so here goes.) [Section 14.21](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.21) of the HTTP/1.1 RFC (2616) explicitly states that "To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an `Expires` date approximately one year from the time the response is sent. **HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send `Expires` dates more than one year in the future.**" (my emphasis)

Comment: Stop writing tags in your titles please.

Answer (score 9):

You could do this:

```
$expire = 'Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+10 years')) . ' GMT';
header($expire);
```

I'm using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to create a timestamp of the current time + 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. Just increase offset to be 10 years in seconds.

Comment: just make sure you take leap years and seconds into account.

Comment: @Salman A I really don't think that precision matters in this case. I find it hard to believe that anything actually *will* cache the resource for ten years (give or that a few leap days and seconds) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set expiration date to one year ahead you need bigger $offset, current is only hour (60 seconds in a minute * 60 minutes in hour).

```
    $offset = 365*24*60*60;
```